# Http not redirecting to Https and it's give me error below

Tags: php, http, npm, https

The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint ''. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
socket.io.js:2 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://demourl.com/path/file.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'https://demourl.com:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M_CFCJq'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: The endpoint URL in the error message you quoted is HTTPS already. Only way I could see this error making sense, would be if that redirected back to the HTTP version …?

Comment: The question is _way_ too unclear. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @04FS - what about if the endpoint URL didn't have a valid certificate (or it was self-signed) - would that result in the error the OP is seeing?

Comment: @CD001 not sure, but I would rather expect a different error message then. If there are certificate issues, then the browser usually says that it could not create a secure connection, but there should be no automatic fallback to considering it an “insecure” resource instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the URL you are using is having HTTPS (SSL)?

On an https webpage, you can only make AJAX request to https webpage.

You should only make requests over HTTPS from your HTTPS application — there is no other workaround for this, and mixing protocols can also put your application security at risk.

Also, check if any other files in your project are on HTTP.